# Generate & Email report from Oracle Forms 11g

Tags: database, oracle, email, oracle11g, oracleforms

I generate a report in PDF through passing of parameters from Oracle Forms 11g. I have a requirement to email the same report automatically as well. Following is the part of forms where I have passed on the parameters.

```
pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata1'); 
add_parameter(pl_id, 'FDT', TEXT_PARAMETER,  :a);
add_parameter(pl_id, 'TDT', TEXT_PARAMETER,  :b);
add_parameter(pl_id, 'VC', TEXT_PARAMETER, :e);
add_parameter(pl_id, 'SYS_DATE', TEXT_PARAMETER, :f);
ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'DESTYPE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'FILE');
ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'DESFORMAT',TEXT_PARAMETER,'PDF');
ADD_PARAMETER(pl_id,'DESNAME',TEXT_PARAMETER,'C:\Downloads\abc.pdf');
```

Now a copy of report is saved in C:\Downloads folder as well as its shown in browser.

I use the following procedure to send current data shown in Forms via emails.

```
create or replace procedure send4 (p_sender IN VARCHAR2, p_recipient IN VARCHAR2, p_subject IN VARCHAR2, p_message IN VARCHAR2)
IS
crlf         VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
l_mailhost VARCHAR2(255) := <IP ADDRESS>;
v_connection             UTL_SMTP.connection;

BEGIN
V_CONNECTION := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
utl_smtp.Helo(V_CONNECTION, l_mailhost);
utl_smtp.Mail(V_CONNECTION, p_sender);
utl_smtp.Rcpt(V_CONNECTION, p_recipient);
utl_smtp.Data(V_CONNECTION,
'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
'From: '   || p_sender || crlf ||
'Subject: '|| p_subject || crlf ||
'To: '     || p_recipient || crlf ||
'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| crlf ||   -- Use MIME mail standard
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| crlf ||
' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
' name="file.txt"'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| crlf ||
'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf ||
' filename="attachment.txt"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf || -- Content of attachment
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND--'         -- End MIME mail
);
UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);
EXCEPTION
WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail', TRUE);
END;
```

1) Can I email the Report generated directly? I tried passing the parameter 'MAIL' and 'Email address' in destype and desname but I am guessing there is some settings need to be done?

OR

2) How can I use the email procedure to send the said report as attachment?

OR

3) How can I copy the report pdf generated in user's PC to a specific directory at server? Because I have one separate procedure for email where I can mail PDFs from server directly. User has Windows PC while server is LINUX.

OR

4) Generate report in PDF format at server directly so I could use the procedure (#3 point) to email it?